# "водопад" - процесс или нет?

Tags: существительные

6. Какое из существительных не обозначает процесс? 
   (А) листопад; (Б) снегопад; (В) звездопад; (Г) водопад; (Д) камнепад.

Задача из конкурса русский медвежонок . В качестве правильного ответа отмечен Г.
Я не согласна с этим ответом. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Согласно толковому словарю Ожегова 
ВОДОПАД, -а,м. Стремительно падающий с высоты поток воды. 
Поскольку для осуществления процесса водопада требуется специальный рельеф, он «привязан к месту», но по существу обозначает именно процесс падения воды, и без падения воды водопадом не является. 
Звездопад в отличие от всех других перечисленных процессов не является процессом падения звезд, а является визуальным эффектом от вхождения метеорита в плотные слои атмосферы земли.

Я считаю, что вопрос поставлен некорректно. Все перечисленные явления являются процессом. Но, на мой взгляд, звездопад можно выделить, поскольку он не отражает процесса падения звезд.

И еще такой вопрос- а какое определение в русском языке понятия "процесс"? Я всречала это слово только применительно к глаголам. А к существительным - это условно или есть определение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Не надо серьезно относиться к задачам из РМ. Я уже несколько раз сталкивался с подобными "откровениями" авторов его задач. Не шибко авторитетный источник.*

По сути "водопад" означает и *процесс* (в понимании авторов), и место, где он происходит. Точно так же "камнепад". А звездопад - не только процесс, но и время. И т.д.
Другое дело, какое из значений словари дают как основное, - это уже от словаря зависит.

Можно еще проанализировать с точки зрения времени существования - процесс всегда имеет начало и конец, а водопад как явление постоянен в рамках субъективного человеческого восприятия. Тут уже ближе. Но опять-таки "камнепад" исключает единственность понимания.

Короче, замысел авторов понятен, но слово "процесс" крайне неудачно выбрано.
Я так думаю.

Думаю, я косвенно ответил на все ваши вопросы. Вот только в отношении самого определения понятия "процесс". ну на бытовом уровне вполне годится определение из любого словаря.

*ПРОЦЕСС, -а; м. [от лат. processus - течение, ход] 1. Последовательная смена состояний в развитии чего-л.; ход, развитие какого-л. явления. П. деления клетки. Мировой исторический п. П. возникновения, развития и упадка общественно-исторических формаций. Происходит медленный п. отступления моря. // Активное развитие болезни. Воспалительный п. У него п. в лёгких. П. развивается быстро....*

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81&all=x

Другие значения - это не наш случай. 
Ясно, что это весьма подходит и к звездопаду, и к водопаду, и к камнепаду. К чему хуже - ну это уж сами решайте.

Comment: Мне кажется вот это всё объясняет: **процесс всегда имеет начало и конец, а водопад как явление постоянен в рамках субъективного человеческого восприятия.**

Comment: Камнепад. Точно так же.

Comment: Составители вопроса аргументируют, что существует правило русского языка, позволяющее выделить существительные, обозначающие процессы по их сочетаемости с фазовыми глаголами.  Помогите, пожалуйста, найти такое. А никогда не встречал понятие " процесс" по отношению к существительному, регламентируемое правилом.

Comment: Фазовый глагол, согласно смыслу термина, обозначает какую-то фазу ситуации - начало, конец, продолжение. Тогда естественно, что фазовый глагол требует контекста ситуации, членимой на фазы. Так, начаться может только процесс или деятельность. Но из этого не следует, что каждый процесс обязательно должен сочетаться с фазовыми глаголами. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Например, мышление - это тоже процесс, но к этому слову невозможно применить фазовые глаголы

Comment: *выделить существительные, обозначающие процессы по их сочетаемости с фазовыми глаголами.* - бррр... Задачу некорректную я еще мог бы простить дядям, но правила придумывать. Может что-то и есть отдаленно напоминающее, но в такой формулировке - вряд ли. Людмила должна вспомнить, если есть такое. Вообще **правила** в языке обычно ограничиваются орфографией (с пунктуацией вкупе). Остальное - от лукавого. В лучшем случае - *закономерности*. Медвежатникам это надо бы знать.

Comment: @behemothus *Очевидцы сняли на видео мощный **камнепад** в Киргизии. Оползень заблокировал стратегическую трассу на Иссык-Куль, в результате образовалась многокилометровая автомобильная пробка.* Не бывает ведь места в природе, где камни падают постоянно, без начала и конца. Для слова _водопад_, как мне кажется, наиболее близкой будет именная группа *сброс воды*. Там как раз есть *начало сброса воды* и *конец сброса воды*.

Comment: *Не бывает ведь места в природе, где камни падают постоянно,* - именно тут вы и ошибаетесь. Вы на права сдавали? "Дорожный знак 1.28." Место падения камней. Довольно наивно считать, что его ставят в местах *однократного* падения. Впрочем, это все не по сути вопроса. Вы уцепились за одну мою мысль, данную как пример ***неверного*** возможного понимания "процесса" авторами задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Водопад - такой же "процесс", как и река. Это участок реки, где вода стекает с уступа вертикально (образно говоря, "падает"). **Этимология** слова и его употребление для **обозначения** понятий - разные вещи. Хотя слово и заключает в себе составляющие, указывающие на "падение воды", обозначает оно не действие или процесс "падения", а географически привязанное понятие, как река или ручей. Водопад не "происходит" (так никогда не говорят, можно только в стишке поиграть словами в этом направлении) - он есть или находится где-то. Не имеет значения, постоянно в нём течёт вода или он время от времени пересыхает; может даже *образоваться* на короткое время после ливня, но никак не "происходить". Если он искусственный (как на горе Хуа Го Шань), его можно выключить, а после включения он будет функционировать как устройство (а не вода в нём снова "запАдает"). К водопаду можно пойти или съездить, в отличие от "камнепада".

Я считаю вопрос корректным и лёгким.

**P.S.** Примером двойственности процесса/явления может, в отличие от "водопада", служить "течение Гольфстрим": слово "течение" способно обозначать и географическое понятие, и связанный с ним процесс движения воды. В нашем же случае для каких-либо процессов с водой слово "водопад" неупотребимо: даже если кто-то выплёскивает из окна воду, оставшуюся после полива цветов, никто из прохожих не назовёт настигший его процесс падения воды "водопадом". Состав слова (**вода - падать**) не должен вводить в заблуждение: ведь в случае со словом "самогон" (**сам - гнать**) ясно, что самогон - напиток, а не процесс приготовления (перегонка).

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Alex_ander.

Comment: А можно, я вас одним вопросом помучаю? Если водопад - не процесс, то что? Вот одним словом, чтобы ясно стало.)))

Comment: Это "водный объект", как и река, ручей, канал и пр.

Comment: Понятно. А камнепад, - значит, неводный объект.)))

Comment: Камнепад - не объект, а процесс. Я допускаю, что где-то есть гиблое место, которое именуют "камнепадом" в значении "объекта" - тогда можно говорить о двойственном значении слова в практике его применения. Но в случае водопада слово относится только к объекту и не применяется к процессам. Иначе падающий с неба дождь (процесс выпадения водных осадков) называли бы "частным случаем водопада", чего не случается.

Answer (score 1):

> > Все перечисленные явления являются процессом

Ниагарский водопад, водопад Виктория, водопад Кивач... Попробуйте произвести то же с камнепадом, звездопадом и особенно с листопадом. "Медвежонок" не рассчитан на то, что дети кинутся к словарям проверять нюансы смыслов. Он рассчитан на *обычных* детей, понимаете? Думаю, что для обычных детей ответ очевиден.

Comment: Вот и плохо, что на "обычных детей". А не на тех, которые желают иметь правильный ответ. А не тот, который им дяди подсовывают.

Comment: (+) А ураганы-тайфуны тогда что? И на Кавказе полно камнепадов с собственными именами...

Comment: А можно попросить пример камнепадов с именами? Не получилось найти

Comment: Признаться, примеров не могу. Надо по военно-грузинской один раз проехать... Там таблички помню. И еще в Теберде что-то такое было...

Comment: Вот именно, "примеров не могу". Потому что это экзотика. А Ниагару и прочие подобные водопады знают все. Нет, если пытаться прицепиться к вопросу, то это можно. Привести пример с тайфунами, например. Только зачем? Кстати, тайфун тоже вряд ли процесс. Тут можно спорить... Но тайфуна и урагана в вопросе нет.

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от контекста "Водопад" является или явлением или процессом.

Comment: Какое из существительных не обозначает процесс?

Comment: О каких существительных вы говорите?

Comment: Это цитата из Вопроса. Посмотрите в текст и увидите!